# Get infinite loop

Tags: html, spring

I use spring security and I get a error who said: This webpage has a redirect loop

```
<security:http pattern="/templates/index.html" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/templates/login.html" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/templates/denied.html" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/js/**" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/imgs/**" security="none"/>

<security:http use-expressions="true">

    <security:form-login
        login-page="/templates/index.html"
        login-processing-url="/templates/j_spring_security_check"
        default-target-url="/templates/main.html"
        always-use-default-target='true'
        authentication-failure-url="/templates/login-error.html"
    />
    <security:logout
        logout-url="/templates/j_spring_security_logout"
        invalidate-session="true"
        logout-success-url="/templates/index.html"
    />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="any"/>

    <security:http-basic />

</security:http>
```

In my index page, i load in the body the content of login

In my login, I have a login and password textfield.

When I click the button, in the body i load the content of another web page

I don't understand why i get this infinite loop

Comment: Every URL is secured. So each request renders a login page, which is protected, which renders a login page, which is protected, which renders a login page... Well you get it. Securing `/**` is probably a bit to broad... You probably want to exclude certain parts to be publicly available.

Comment: i was thinking then <security:http pattern="/templates/index.html" security="none"/> said don't put any security for this page

Comment: A sorry, missed those. make sure that you covred all parts which can be accessed freely.